# Bolt size for Sora BL-3500 flat bar brake lever

Tags: size, bolt

I purchased a pair of [Sora BL-3500 brake levers](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/sora-3500/BL-3500.html) second hand.  These were sold without handlebar clamp bolts.  I optimistically thought I could re-use the ones from my old mid 1990's Shimano brake lever and shifter combination.  Turns out they are of a different [pitch](https://www.mtbr.com/threads/clamp-bolts-for-shimano-xtr-shifters.416315/).  I have been trying to confirm the correct size, but can't find the specification for this model.  I do find a specification for other models (including recent model MTB brake levers): M5 x 18 (and I believe 1.0 pitch).

Is this the correct bolt size for my Sora brake levers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're very likely to be M6 x 1.0mm pitch. I'm not sure how long, but its probably within the 15-20mm range, and you can easily measure that yourself with a ruler or something. This is the same diameter as your headset preload bolt, so you could use that to verify if needed.

**M5** x 1.0 doesn't readily exist. The standard thread pitch for **M5** is 0.8mm. The standard pitch for **M6** is 1.0mm.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with a headset preload bolt to see if it matches!

Comment: Headset preload bolt fits, length should be about 18mm if it's not to stick out too much.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Superman.Lopez My pleasure.